# From where wp ecommerce is loading plugin theme files?

Tags: wordpress

I updated my checkout page by updating mostly the file which was in ....wp-ecommerce/wpsc-theme/wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php

It worked fine for a while, but now some of the changed states reverted to the previous state. Actually, I can even delete the file that I mentioned above, so it means wordpress is loading this file from somewhere else. Any ideas from where and what had happened? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have a specific answer to your question, if you use an IDE (like Dreamweaver or Eclipse) you could grab a copy of your sites code to your local PC and do a code search for something that is unique to that page.

Ie, if there is a `<div class="a_unique_div">` tag somewhere on that page and you know it's only visible on that page, search the code for that and it may give you a clue what file is being used for the output.  Even if it's only used on 1 or 2 pages it may bring you closer to working it out.

Alternatively, if you have SSH access you could try and "grep" for the code by SSHing into your server and running a command like:

```
grep -i -R '<div class="a_unique_div">' /www/your_wp_folder/
```

(where /www/your_wp_folder/ is the path to your WordPress installation)

Though for this you'll need SSH access, grep installed on the server, etc, so it may not be a viable option.

Good luck!